# Running external executable from Design Automation job?

Tags: autodesk, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

The goal is to run a c++ executable from a Revit DA job in order to do some mesh processing using a 3rd party library. I'm investigating that track first so it removes the need to write custom .Net bindings to interact with the c++ lib...
Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
[10/04/2023 19:46:31] Exception RunMeshOptimizer: Not enough quota is available to process this command
[10/04/2023 19:46:31] StackTrace:    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
[10/04/2023 19:46:31]    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
[10/04/2023 19:46:31]    at Keystone.DA.Revit.Net.Commands.RunMeshOptimizer(JObject opts, String inputFile, String outputFile)
```

The c++ test code is very straightforward so I doubt it consumes a lot of memory:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    std::ofstream outfile("test.txt");

    outfile << "test" << std::endl;

    outfile.flush();
    outfile.close();
}
```

The executable is included in the DA bundle and invoked from .Net as follow:

```
var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.Location), "MeshOptimizer.exe");

using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
   exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

My question is if there is any kind of known limitation in spawning external exe from a DA job?

Comment: There is no additional restrictions than a revit app bundle has. But a question, will this exe somehow use Revit API? How? If not this setup will cost you more than it needs to.

Comment: ok thanks, the c++ tool won't use the Revit API but we don't have a better environment to execute c++ or .Net code in the cloud so we will be ok paying for DA execution time... how do you suggest moving forward debugging that issue?

Comment: @Felipe I seem not able to reproduce this issue by following your code snippets. Could you help check if the Exception RunMeshOptimizer: Not enough quota is available to process this command is from your appbundle, and check what the actual output file size of your `RunMeshOptimizer .exe` on the local machine is? Here is my test case: https://github.com/yiskang/RevitExternalExeTestCase . Meanwhile, to continue investigating this issue, we will need your help to provide more details.

Comment: @Felipe  Could you also include the argument `adskDebug` when submitting workitems to see if your output file is visible in the downloaded `debuginfo` zip? Just want to ensure your output file is generated under the current working dir. https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/using-argument-adskdebug-troubleshot-failure-job-design-automation

Comment: Thanks for taking time to put a full sample together. Today when testing again the exe I no longer get the quota error and output file works fine. That exception was definitely coming from my bundle code to answer your question. Maybe it was a temporary glitch from DA service. Anyway for the time being I can take it from there and I will let you know if it occurs again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's great to hear the good news, Felipe! No problem, feel free to get back to me if the issue occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

In general, running custom programs should be possible on **Design Automation** servers: [Run additional programs inside a WorkItem](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/run-additional-programs-inside-workitem) 
The problem might be specific to running the **exe** from inside a **Revit app bundle** (the team will investigate that) and running it **after** the **RevitCoreConsole** finished should be fine.

I did check running a custom **exe** on **DA4R** server and that worked fine for me:
[image]

So, I guess you could just run your custom **exe** as a second item in the **commandLine** array. This is the first solution in the blog post I referenced above - something like:

```
"commandLine": [
  "$(engine.path)\\RevitCoreConsole.exe /al \"$(appbundles[MyBundle].path)\"",
  "\"$(appbundles[MyBundle].path)\\MyBundlePlugin.bundle\\Contents\\MeshOptimizer.exe\""
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it will even further complicate things as the exe is supposed to produce an output file which then get zipped with other json files produced as previous steps running Revit API. Running all those steps from Tevit plugin is more convenient…